Combined with hardhat gas reporter, the API for Coinmarketcap has been set, but Coinmarketcap cannot obtain the price of USD,
I used coinmarketcap and hardhat-gas-reporter to get usd price，but I run "yarn hardhat test",and the gas-report.txt have not usd price,this is my config:
gasReporter: {
  enabled: true,
  outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
  noColors: true,
  currency: "USD",
  coinmarketcap: COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
  token: "ETH",
},

this is version of package.json:"hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.7","ethers": "^6.4.0","hardhat": "^2.22.4",
I suspect it may be an issue with the hardhat gas reporter version or with the Coinmarketcap network

maybe you can add 'gasPrice' to try , ps.
gasReporter: 
{
        enabled: true,
        outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
        noColors: true,
        currency: "USD",
        coinmarketcap: COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
        gasPrice: 21,
}

